# Error is not thrown inside a deferred method

Tags: node.js, exception, deferred

Can somebody explain to me why my error is not thrown in my first example? And why it is when I use `process.nextTick()` ?

```
var deferred = require('deferred');

// This code does not work. 
// Error seems to never been thrown and script kind of freeze without saying anything.
deferred.resolve().then(function(){
    console.log('deferred resolved');
    throw new Error('Synchronous error thrown in deferred.then()');
});

// This code does work. 
// I just embedded the throw in the process.nextTick() method.
deferred.resolve().then(function(){
    console.log('deferred resolved');
    process.nextTick(function(){
        throw new Error('Synchronous error thrown in deferred.then()');
    });
});
```

Why do I need to wait the nextTick to throw an error inside the `then()`   ...

Any explanation will be appreciated.
Thx

I have seen this post ([No errors thrown/displayed when in a deferred callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572821/no-errors-thrown-displayed-when-in-a-deferred-callback)). But it gives only half an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `deferred` seems reasonable to me in your cases.

In the second case, I don't think that `deferred` has a way to catch the error thrown in the `nextTick` callback. So the error is thrown.

In the first case, `deferred` catches it and considers that that resulting promise in in failed state. The `deferred` documentation states that if you want it to effectively throw an error that pushed the promise into failed state, you have to call `done`

```
deferred.resolve().then(function(){
  console.log('deferred resolved');
  throw new Error('Synchronous error thrown in deferred.then()');
}).done();
```

See https://github.com/medikoo/deferred#ending-chain for documentation

Comment: Thanks. That's what I understood after asking (at least for the chain-ending of the first case). And I guess you are right about `process.nextTick()` : it should probably get the inside-function out of the deferred workflow and then it does not catch the error. Thanks for having confirmed my thought.